# Python3.5 - reading excel data using thread

Tags: excel, multithreading, python-3.5

I need your super help that I can't read excel data using thread.
My code is below..If I don't use thread, it works. 
but If I use thread I got and error below.

=========================================================================
[image]

=========================================================================

```
import os, sys, xlrd, win32com.client, threading, time, pythoncom
from time import sleep

class ExcelCheck(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.event = threading.Event()


def run(self):
    while not self.event.is_set():
        win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application").Wait()
        excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        wb = excel.ActiveWorkbook
        ws = wb.Worksheets("sample")

        va_title = ws.Range(ws.Range('I1'), ws.Range('I100'))


        i = 0
        for r in va_title.Cells:
            if r.Text != '':
                i = i + 1

        print(i)
        sleep(3)
        self.event.wait( )

def stop(self):
    self.event.set()

tmr = ExcelCheck()

tmr.start()

time.sleep(100)

tmr.stop()
```

Comment: I solved my self. don't need to solve this.

Comment: You can just input pythoncom.CoInitialize() beloew def run(self)